# How to write integration tests for WebExtensions (loading, checking some expectations, unloading)?

Tags: javascript, selenium, integration-testing, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is there a way to write integration tests for WebExtension based Browser addons?

In addition to unit tests, I would like to write an integration test that fully loads an extension, performs some tests, and finally unloads it.

---

My own research:

I assume it is possible with Selenium, but from my experience Selenium can lead to flakey tests that are hard to maintain. I wonder if there is a lighter alternative. Could also be that Selenium is the tool of choice. I have to admit that I don't have much experience with testing Browser extensions.

For limited use cases, I have used [mock-browser](https://github.com/darrylwest/mock-browser). But as far as I understand it, it is not possible to simulate loading and unloading extensions with it.

---

Example:

To get an idea what kind of tests I would like to automate, here is a small example of a manual test that we have:

- Start a browser with the extension. If the extension loads correctly, it will start increase a counter periodically
- (Manually) check whether the counter increases. If the counter increases, the test passes.

If the test environment support loading an extension, this manual test could be easily automated. The problem is just to setup an environment that allows to load the extension. Currently, we run our unit tests with Node and using Mocha as a test framework.

Comment: Yes it's possible to write integration tests for WebExtension. Though, you'll probably have to rephrase your post with a more specific question to get an answer. Selenium is an automation library and not a testing framework, so the flakiness and maintainability mainly depend on how you design/code your tests.